# Prestashop Add extra fields to registration form

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopping-cart, prestashop, oscommerce

I am building a prestashop site

The corporate buyers cannot register for an account to view the products unless they can enter a valid EIN number or a valid Duns & Brandstreet number in registration.

How to make it possible?

Also any other e-commerce software that can help me solve this by switching to it?

Answer (score 1):

All you really need to do is add the field to the template and then override the `AuthController` with additional code to handle you new field. e.g.

```
<?php
class AuthController extends AuthControllerCore
{     
  public function preProcess()
  {
    // Additional pre-processing for the new form field
    if (Tools::isSubmit('submitAccount'))
    {
      if (!MyDBNumberValidationClass::verifyvalidnumber(Tools::getValue('db_number_field', 0)))
        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The Dun and Bradstreet number you entered is invalid.'); 
    }
    parent::preProcess();
  }
}
```

I'm assuming that you're doing complex verification of the number which is why the static call to `MyDBNumberValidationClass::verifyvalidnumber()` is in the above, but it could equally by any simple test or an additional function in your `AuthController` override class definition above that validates. If you add two fields (i.e. the EIN number too) then just alter the logic to handle generating an error only if **both** are invalid; success of the form validation is based on `$this->errors` being empty.

This is only part of a general solution since it only handles **validating** the extra fields. If you need to actually do something with the data entered then the best way is to write a little handler module that installs itself on `hookCreateAccount` e.g.

```
public function hookCreateAccount($params)
{
  // Get the field data entered on the form
  $DB_number = $params['_POST']['db_number_field'];

  // Your custom processing...
}
```

Note that there's no way to back out of the account creation from here so you will want to add code to email the store owner should there be a problem.